# Is this question really off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

I am still pondering over this question that I asked the other day:

["High-pitched": one word or two words?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166610/high-pitched-one-word-or-two-words)

It received a close vote very early on for being off-topic, and is currently sitting on three. I guess the reason I decided to post on Meta is I really consider that question a good one: necessary and thought-out. I don't think it is off-topic. Intuitively, a word like *lily-livered* would be one hyphenated compound word, and when that is belied by MW material, I found it helpful to have it clarified so that I'd know how to describe such words in the future, say, if I need to ask questions on ELL/ELU about such words. I don't believe answers to such a question would help just me.

For example, I'd hesitate about which term to use when making comments like [this one by FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116644/a-word-that-means-to-become-ones-name#comment238018_116644) (*Some people might say aptly-named counts as **a "hyphenated word"***). I could be wrong as some of the comments under my question are gone, but I remember FumbleFingers to be the first person that cast a close vote on my question. FumbleFingers apparently also considered this matter indeterminate, let alone English learners. Then shouldn't there be a discussion on the correct terminology? I want to be able to discuss these words without hesitation or uncertainty, and I bet so do a lot of other people.

P.S.:

J.R. thought my question's context wasn't clear, which was an oversight on my part (linked the page but forgot to mention the source of my confusion was in the audio) and which I promptly fixed. I withheld the MW source in the first posting, because I didn't want to make the question unclear and I thought the question was sufficient in context. It was supposed to be a simple question: "Are they single words and why?"

**Edit:**

Here is one instance where the distinction matters and comes relevant on ELL. I just posted [a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167872/the-meaning-of-slow-boiling-in-this-sentence) on ELL about the meaning of a hyphenated compound. I paused when picking the appropriate tags because I wasn't sure if I should include the "word-meaning" tag, as whether *slow-boiling* is a word is apparently inconclusive.

Comment: It takes some time for close votes to age away. The first close vote on your question was a week ago and it's still not closed, so your edits may have improved the question enough to prevent closure.

Comment: @ColleenV I understand. I guess I just disagree with the opinion that such questions are off-topic. The first posting, not without flaws in clarity, was a simple and much-needed question. I understand and agree with edit suggestions on clarity and more information.

Comment: @ColleenV - Two of the three close votes were cast before the question was edited, so it appears that the edit helped a lot.

Comment: @L.Moneta Well, I certainly hope you wouldn't ask a question that you thought was off-topic! We don't always agree about whether something should remain open or not; that's why it takes 5 votes to close a question and why it's pretty easy for a question to get into the "reopen" queue after it has been put on hold.

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe I should add, I don't understand how anyone could see it as off-topic...

Comment: I suppose that my first thought is - why does it matter? How does knowing whether it's one word or two get you - if there's any specific answer to that question anyone can provide? That's what I'm not sure about. Now, that doesn't make it off topic ... me not caring about the answer... but if it's not going to help you learn English (which I'm not sure how it does), how *does* it relate to a site dedicated to helping people learn English?

Comment: @Catija Some distinctions, of course, are more important for learners to know than others. I'd agree telling nouns from adjectives is more helpful than knowing how demonstratives and distributives are different. But I doubt a dismissive "Oh, that's too advanced. You don't need to know that." is ever a good answer. Whether there is any specific or definitive answer is part of the question. If there is, if the definitive answer is "single word" and if my question has the honor of being seen by many, next time someone compares transgendered and four-legged, they would have more of a basis.

Comment: It's not about being too advanced. I'm a native speaker and I have no clue what the answer is and... I've survived 36 years without that knowledge... and intend to continue my life without the information. It serves no purpose. Whether it's a single word or two doesn't *mean* anything. I really don't see how the transgender discussion relates.

Comment: @Catija The vast majority of native English speakers have no idea what a determiner is, but it doesn't mean the concept of determiner is trifling or irrelevant. I can't remember how many times I have seen _determiner_ mentioned on ELL (Oh, 820 hits among questions and unnumbered in comments? Thank you ELL Search Tool)

Comment: Again, I'm not sure how knowing what a determiner is relates to this. Determiners are a part of *how* learners are taught. Learners, as far as I'm aware, aren't taught whether hyphenated words are actually a single word or two... Anyway, you asked why, I explained. Arguing about whether my explanation is valid or not is beside the point.

Comment: @Catija No, not really. In fact, it's very likely an ESL/EFL learner knows _article_ but not _determiner_. I just checked some ESL/EFL textbooks in two other languages (up to high school level). They all have chapters/passages on articles and qualifiers, but nothing about _the concept of_ determiner. In fact, in one of the two languages I am familiar with besides English, the word "determiner" doesn't seem to appear except in advanced grammar books (college/graduate level English/linguistics books).

Comment: @Catija Anyways, yes, you did answer my question here and I appreciate it. Just trying to offer a different side of the matter for consideration. Part of your judgment of the (ir)relevance of my question comes from the fact that you are a native speaker (actually as concepts and terminology go, linguistics background + being a native speaker would probably be more apropos), and that is what learners lack and why learners (at least some) would like to know. Doesn't your conviction help prove my point a bit?

Comment: Probably not. I still don't see how the question being discussed is of value to anyone, learner or otherwise... but I also *didn't* vote to close it... so it's sort of irrelevant.